# Selecting a class underneath a class with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to select a class underneath a class, say I have a class named "A" on an element, and under it, I've got another element with a class name of "B".

There are other instances of "B" in the DOM, but none of them but one is under "A".

To select ONLY the "B" under the "A", would I use:

```
.A B {

CSS HERE

}
```

Or am I doing it wrong?

Here's the structure:

```
<h2 class="A">
<span>TITLECONTENT</span>
</h2>
<p>CONTENT</p>
<div class="B" addthis:title="TITLECONTENT " addthis:url="URL">
```

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. It may be a different problem. I'm trying to hide all elements with a certain class, except for elements which are under elements of a specific class.

Answer (score 5):

The most general form is

```
.A .B { ... }
```

This will target any element with class B which has a parent with class A, whether it is a direct parent or not:

```
<span class="B">
    <span class="A" >
    </span>
</span>
```

as well as

```
<span class="B">
    <div>
        <span class="A" >
        </span>
    <div>
</span>
```

---

If `.B` is a direct children of `.A` you can target it with this:

```
.A > .B { ... }
```

[CSS Child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)

Answer (score 4):

no you forgot the dot,

```
.A .B {

}
```

(assuming you mean your html is like this:)

```
<div class="A">
   <div class="B"></div>
</div>
```

Whenever you reference a class, you use a `.`
Whenever you reference an id, you use a `#`
Whenever you reference a tag name, you use no prefix e.g. `div {}`

Use the least [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) you need to target different elements

Targeting an element with multiple classes you append the second class with no space: .one.two

Targeting a descendant element you include a space: .one .descendant

Comment: Thank you! I thought I may have the syntax ALMOST correct, but not quite.

Comment: To target a child element you use `>`, not a space. The space is for all descendants (child, grandchild, etc)

Answer (score 0):

almost correct. 
You have to do

`.A .B` <- please note dot before B.

Also, if in the future you would need to select an element that has BOTH ` and B at the same time, you do it like this:

```
.A.B
```

which would target something like div class="A B" but will NOT target div class="A" nor div class="B"

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a dot, but if you want all class B elements that are directly under class A elements, use the greater-than sign. So A has to be the direct parent of B.

```
.A > .B {
    /* CSS here. */
}
```